# CSS artificially simulated italic font-style

Tags: css, pdfkit

The [MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style) mention this for the property italic font-style:

> Selects a font that is classified as italic. If no italic
>   version of the face is available, one classified as oblique is used
>   instead. If neither is available, **the style is artificially simulated**.

How is this style artificially simulated? Is there a certain angle it uses to slant the text? If so, what is the angle?

I'm creating PDF documents with pdfkit that need to mimic the front end editor app as closely as possible, but I don't know how to approach this when italics come in play for fonts that don't have an italic version.